# Does dvips's "ps:" special alter the standard PostScript (bp) units?

Tags: dvips, output-driver

Working on developing some clipping code based on the approach taken by `pgf`, I've stumbled across some odd effects with the `\special{ps:` construct of `dvips`. A couple of examples will show this. The first is doing some simple drawing:

```
\def\squaredemo{%
  newpath
  0 0 moveto
  0 72 lineto
  72 72 lineto
  72 0 lineto
  closepath
  stroke
}

\vbox to 72bp%
  {\special{" \squaredemo}}
\vbox to 72bp%
  {\special{ps: gsave \squaredemo grestore}}
\bye
```

The two operations should be equivalent: according to the `dvips` manual, the `"` form of the special inserts a save/restore but other than that is the same as `ps:`. However, the output of the two is different: the square in the second case is a lot smaller.

The second case, and the one that led me to this, is seen when you do some clipping:

```
\newbox\tmpbox

\setbox\tmpbox=\hbox{\vrule width 1in height 1in depth 0 in }
\noindent\box\tmpbox

\setbox\tmpbox=\hbox{\vrule width 1in height 1in depth 0 in }
\setbox\tmpbox=\hbox{%
  \special{ps:gsave}%
  \special{
    ps:
      currentpoint
      currentpoint translate
      /savedmatrix matrix currentmatrix def
      Resolution 72 div VResolution 72 div scale
      0 0 36 -72 rectclip
      savedmatrix setmatrix
      neg exch neg exch translate
  }%
  \wd\tmpbox 0pt %
  \rlap{\box\tmpbox}%
  \special{ps:grestore}%
  \hskip 0.5in %
}
\noindent\box\tmpbox 

\setbox\tmpbox=\hbox{\vrule width 1in height 1in depth 0 in }
\setbox\tmpbox=\hbox{%
  \special{ps:gsave}%
  \special{
    ps:
      currentpoint
      currentpoint translate
      /savedmatrix matrix currentmatrix def
      Resolution VResolution scale
      0 0 0.5 -1 rectclip
      savedmatrix setmatrix
      neg exch neg exch translate
  }%
  \wd\tmpbox 0pt %
  \rlap{\box\tmpbox}%
  \special{ps:grestore}%
  \hskip 0.5in %
}
\noindent\box\tmpbox
\bye
```

Notice that to get the clipping to behave correctly you need to scale by a factor which seems to be the `Resolution`.

So the question is why this is happening: standard PostScript units should be big points. Is this something 'built in' to `dvips`, is it specific to the `ps:` special or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Note that if you apply the matrix business to the `ps:` case for the square then the problem once again 'goes away'. Also, you only see this with absolute lengths, so scalings/rotations are unaffected. What I'm therefore after is not so much a fix as an explanation!

Comment: For testing, it's advantageous to set `\nopagenumbers` as this makes the PostScript files much smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clue to this mystery is the resolution set in `config.ps`: in my case 600 dpi. A bit of experimentation reveals that the scale needed to get things 'right' here is roughly 8.333, *i.e.* 600/72 or the number of dots per PostScript point required for a 600 dpi image.

Reading carefully over the PostScript file you find a small section that reads

```
TeXDict begin 39158280 55380996 1000 600 600 (test.dvi)
@start end
```

If you then look up the definition of `@start`, it's clear that this picks up the two `600` here as the horizontal and vertical  resolutions, respectively. That can be verified by using a fixed scaling and altering these values.

What is happening is that `dvips` sets up to use this resolution for inclusion of material, but when you use the 'shortcut' `"` syntax for specials it inserts `@beginspecial @setspecial` before your code and `@endspecial` after. More digging reveals that `@beginspecial` includes `normalscale`, which is defined to reverse the scaling `dvips` has applied (and also to allow for a `\mag`).

Thus some form of scaling operation is definitely required. The approach using the 'hand coded' scaling, as in the question, clearly works. It may be possible to subvert `@beginspecial`/`@endspecial` within a `\special{ps:` or `\special{ps::` call, but this seems to be non-trivial as there is 'extra' stuff also happening behind the scenes, depending on the case. It is doable in a raw edit of the PostScript file, but only seems to work from the TeX file in the more trivial first example and not in the clipping case.

Importantly, this variation in behaviour does not appear to be documented in the `dvips` manual.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look into the ps file. If you insert the scaling `600 72 div dup scale` you'll get the same.

```
 gsave newpath 
 600 72 div dup scale 
0 0 moveto 0 72 lineto 72 72 lineto 72 0 lineto closepath
stroke grestore
```

or:

```
\vbox to 72bp%
  {\special{ps: gsave 600 72 div dup scale \squaredemo grestore}}
```

the correct internal values are /DVImag and /Resolution

Comment: Certainly the code I have currently doesn't allow for the DVI magnification issue

Comment: but you can do `\special{ps: @beginspecial @setspecial \squaredemo @endspecial }` which is the same.

Comment: Yes, I edited in the fact this works for the simple case: doesn't however for the more complicated one involving clipping. (The simple box demo could have been done using just `\special{" ...` in any case.)